# Непрерывная работа скрипта на web-сервере

Tags: php, javascript

Такая задача, нужно  заставить отрабатывать один скрипт на сайте через определенное время, желательно чтобы это был js, либо чтобы это был php который запускает код js. Как правильно реализовать? Хочу чтобы скрипт отрабатывал каждый час. Подчеркиваю, важно чтобы js скрипт не был зависим от страницы с которой его запустили. Логика такая, со страницы запускается php, которому должно быть все равно на сайте пользователь, который запустил код  или нет. Скрипт к примеру постоянно должен пинговать один домен и ложит все это в логи. Как заставить php работать постоянно? Чтобы я зашел на страницу настроек скрипта, поставил интервал, запустил его и забыл, а он работает.

Я правильно понимаю что просто закинуть все в `while(true)` не поможет?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь командой 'crontab -e'

Comment: В nodejs - это несложная задача. `setTimeout` функции, интервал для которого берёте из кеша(memcached/redis/regularfile). Страничка с интервалом меняет его же.

Comment: @vp_arth, я смогу дергать api для js используя node.js? И я так понимаю на арендованном хостинге у меня не будет доступа к  memcached/redis/regularfile?

Comment: regularfile - значит просто файл. Вы не можете создать файл? Тогда поместите это в базу данных. В конце концов, держите это дело прямо в памяти/переменной nodejs. Понятия не имею, что значит "api для js". nodejs - это и есть js.

Comment: @vp_arth, понял, спасибо, думал что это какой-то системный файл) Буду копать, спасибо ещё раз

Comment: используйте `Crontab` который по хорошему должен быть установлен на хостинге или сервере. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 1):

Допустим так:

```
set_time_limit(0); // неограниченное время выполнения скрипта
ignore_user_abort(true);
function task() {
  // Код задачи
}
while (true) {
  task();
  $delay = file_get_contents('delay.cfg'); // период повтора в секундах
  sleep($delay);
}
```

Админка должна редактировать файл `delay.cfg`

Нужно реализовать защиту от многократного запуска скрипта, на семафорах или в файл писать таймстемп последней итерации, если прошло слишком много времени - разрешать повторный запуск.

*Хостер имеет возможность ограничивать максимальное время работы скриптов.*